# One time only bootup script on a pi

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

I've got some software (mainly python, .sh and cron etc.) in Git that I'm pulling down during a boot up of my Pi to ensure I always have the latest code running.  I'm new to Unix and Git. I have a number of Pis so I'm effectively trying to automate the distribution and keep them all up to date each time they boot.

I've got a MySQL DB involved and I've just added some new tables.

What I want to do now is to pull down a script file that will create a table and set some default values, but I don't want to do this every time I boot up or it will potentially set data values back to the default on each boot... no good.

What I've got so far is a .sh file that is run via crontab at reboot.  This file does the Git pull, then moves files around and sorts things out.

What I'd planned to do was add a command along the lines of the following to my boot .sh file:

```
sudo MySQL --batch -h localhost -u root --password=PASSWORD -D databasename < sqlscript > outfile.log
```

The sqlscript file would contain the `CREATE TABLE` commands, `UPDATE` etc.

But what I can't work out is how to only do this once?

Options considered:

- I could delete the sqlscript after I've run it, but I'd then get an error from the .sh file each time I boot.
- I could replace the .sh file once its run once with one without the MYSQL command in it... but then if a Pi gets behind versions and jumps several versions in an upgrade I'd miss out on the intermediate .sh file with the SQL tables being
- I could do something really complex by adding version numbers all over the place but this is too much work for now.
- I could perhaps check if the table doesn't exist already by selecting from the `TABLES` table, if it does skip the script, if not exectute it?  This is currently likely the way forward, anyone got a sample script to check this... I've not done if statements in a shell script before.

I suspect this has been done many times before so any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a flag file, say

```
/root/run-database-init
```

It doesn't have to contain anything, just exist as you'll be testing for its existence in your init script and delete it afterward:

```
if [ -f /root/run-database-init ]; then
     # do stuff with mysql...
     rm /root/run-database-init
fi
```

Comment: great, thanks Jean-Karim,  I did it the other way round and it worked like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

if ! [ -f chkfile ]; then

touch chkfile

MySQL  blah blah

else

echo  Found chkfile so skipping table creates

fi

(not sure why its not indenting, but its 2 char indents)